# Azure web app list is empty on publish

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

When I try to publish a web app to azure (using VS2015), I get an empty list for my subscription (developer program benefits)

I have managed to successfully create a web app service through the azure portal, and it's assigned to that subscription.

Have I made a schoolboy error and missed some configuration option?

Comment: did you add your subscription to VS?

Comment: Yes, it's displayed in the vs wizard and it shows my account correctly.

Comment: I can see the app service in the azure explorer, but nothing when trying to publish via web deploy.